# How to find this kernel and image?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good morning. How to find the kernel and the image of $T(p(x))=xp(x)-3p'(x)$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to n? I'm lost, I know solve homogeneous systems on $\mathbb{R}$, but this does not. Thanks!

Comment: If your space is "polynomials with degree less than or equal to $n$", then $T(x^n) = x^{n+1} - 3nx^{n-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n + 1$. So _where_ is $T$ defined? On the space of _all_ polynomials? Or is it a map $T:P_n \to P_{n+1}$ from the space of at-most-degree-$n$-polynomials to the space of at-most-degree-$(n+1)$-polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the kernel, you need to solve $T(p(x))=0$, which gives you the differential equation $$xp(x)-3p'(x)=0.$$

The solutions are $$ p(x)=Ke^{\frac{x^2}6},$$

which aren't polynomial unless $K=0$.

So $\text{ker}(T)=\{0\}$.

You can now check that $T$ is a linear operator between to finite space which are respectively polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$, and polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n+1$.

So by the rank-nullity theorem, you know that the image of $T$ has dimension $n+1$.